# PySpark: How to Update Nested Columns?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

StackOverflow has a few answers on how to update nested columns in a dataframe. However, some of them looks a bit complex.

While searching, I found this documentation from DataBricks that handles the same scenarios: https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/faq/update-nested-column.html

```
val updated = df.selectExpr("""
    named_struct(
        'metadata', metadata,
        'items', named_struct(
          'books', named_struct('fees', items.books.fees * 1.01),
          'paper', items.paper
        )
    ) as named_struct
""").select($"named_struct.metadata", $"named_struct.items")
```

That looks pretty clean as well. Unfortunately though, I don't know Scala. How would I translate this to Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might help you get started; converted your Databricks link to python using a 1 row ex. for you to explore

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema = StructType()\
.add("metadata", StructType()\
     .add("eventid", IntegerType(), True)\
     .add("hostname", StringType(), True)\
     .add("timestamp", StringType(), True))\
.add("items", StructType()\
     .add("books", StructType()\
         .add("fees", DoubleType(), True))\
     .add("paper", StructType()\
         .add("pages", IntegerType(), True)))

nested_row = [

    (
        {
            "metadata": {
                "eventid": 9,
                "hostname": "999.999.999",
                "timestamp": "9999-99-99 99:99:99"
            },
            "items": {
                "books": {
                    "fees": 99.99
                },

                "paper": {
                    "pages": 9999
                }
            }
        }
    )
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(nested_row, schema)

df.printSchema()

df.selectExpr("""
    named_struct(
        'metadata', metadata,
        'items', named_struct(
          'books', named_struct('fees', items.books.fees * 1.01),
          'paper', items.paper
        )
    ) as named_struct
""").select(col("named_struct.metadata"), col("named_struct.items"))\
.show(truncate=False)

root
 |-- metadata: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- eventid: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- hostname: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- items: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- books: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- fees: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- paper: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- pages: integer (nullable = true)

+-------------------------------------+-----------------+
|metadata                             |items            |
+-------------------------------------+-----------------+
|[9, 999.999.999, 9999-99-99 99:99:99]|[[99.99], [9999]]|
+-------------------------------------+-----------------+

+-------------------------------------+------------------------------+
|metadata                             |items                         |
+-------------------------------------+------------------------------+
|[9, 999.999.999, 9999-99-99 99:99:99]|[[100.98989999999999], [9999]]|
+-------------------------------------+------------------------------+
```

Comment: can you please link to the pyspark docs where it describes the usage of this `named_struct`?