# Convert string type column to struct column in pyspark

Tags: json, dataframe, pyspark

I have a dataframe which has nested structure in it, so I know for sure it is a structType, however since it was converted from a json, it's inferring the schema as string instead of struct. I would like it to remain struct. How should I approach this problem?

The dataframe currently looks like this:

```
 _________________________________________________________________
|issuingClub |              memberCards                           |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1234      |[{u'createdClub': u'1234', u'cardStatus': u'ACTIVE',| 
             | u'issuedReason': u'new member', u'cardType':       |
             | u'MEMBERSHIPACCOUNT', u'cardNumber':u'109214092'}] |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| 3712       |[{u'createdClub': u'3712', u'cardStatus': u'EXPIRE',| 
             | u'issuedReason': u'old member', u'cardType':       |
             | u'MEMBERSHIPACCOUNT', u'cardNumber':u'109214092'}] |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The schema for this dataframe is being inferred as:

```
 root:
   |-- issuingClub: string (nullable = true)
   |-- memberCards: string (nullable = true)
```

Instead of memberCards being string, I would like to convert it into StructType. How do I do this? PLease help!

I have tried using this code:

```
 import json

 def parse_json(array_str):
     json_obj = json.loads(array_str)
     for item in json_obj:
         yield (item["createdClub"],item["cardStatus"],item["issuedReason"],item["cardType"],item["cardNumber"])


from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, IntegerType, StructType, StructField
json_schema = ArrayType(StructType([StructField("u'createdClub", StringType(), nullable=False), StructField("u'cardStatus", StringType(), nullable=False),
                                StructField("u'issuedReason", StringType(), nullable=False),
                                StructField("u'cardType",StringType(),nullable=False),
                                StructField("u'cardNumber",StringType(),nullable=False)]))

from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

udf_parse_json = udf(lambda str: parse_json(str), json_schema)

df_new = old_df.select(delta_final_df["issuingClub"], udf_parse_json(delta_final_df["memberCards"]).alias("memberCards"))
```

Getting this error as a result of that:

```
ValueError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)
```

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55892939/nested-dynamic-schema-not-working-while-parsing-json-using-pyspark/55893241#55893241

Comment: @thePurplePython afraid not. I changed my approach and converted the string to map type instead.

Comment: if you data is json source just try reading the data via the spark json reader

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? @iratelilkid